# Something I do not understand about dictionaries

Tags: python

When I was trying to understand Python dictionaries, I compared the output of two programs. I don't understand why the output is different.

Both programs start with

```
data = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value3'
        }
```

First program:

```
for keys in data.items():
    print keys
```

Second program:

```
for keys, values in data.items():
    print keys, values
```

The outputs are

```
('key3', 'value3')
('key2', 'value2')
('key1', 'value1')
```

and

```
key3 value3
key2 value2
key1 value1
```

Why does the first  output show parenthesised strings?

Why doesn't the second output show the commas?

Comment: Naming your dummy variable 'keys' in your first program creates confusion. You could name it 'item' (or, in fact, any name): for item in data.items(): print item As stated above, dict.items() returns key/value pairs (dictionary items) in the form of tuples. And tuples, because order matters: {'key':'value'} is not the same as {'value':'key'}. If I may ask a follow-up question: Why do keys() and values() return lists, which are ordered, instead of e.g. sets to reflect the unorderedness of items in a dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dict.items` returns a sequence of 2-tuples, of (key, value).

What happens in the first example is that you're taking a single element from the that at at time, which in this case is the whole tuple (key, value). When you use `for key, value in` Python performs "unpacking" which means it assigns the first element of that tuple to key to key and the next element to value, so you can access them as separate variables.

When you print those, Python prints a tuple (your first example), as `(1, 2)`, but when it's unpacked and you print two separate variables, it prints the number `1` followed by the number `2` with a space in between.

Answer (score 6):

`dict.items` return a list of tuples of key, value pairs. If only one name in the for, it 
assigns the tuple to the name. With two names, it unpacks the key, value to the names separately. See:

```
>>> a, b = (1, 2)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> a
(1, 2)
>>>
```